# Cast of a Generic Type in .NET

Tags: .net, generics

Why is the following cast not working ?

```
public void Add<T>() where T : MyInterface
{
   var newObject = new Factory<T>() as Factory<MyInterface>;

   ...
}

public class Factory<T> where T : MyInterface 
{ ... }
```

newObjects always remains null.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx

Comment: Code smell: Why do you use generics here then ... :/ Either it is generic or explicit ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `Factory<T>` is not a subtype of `Factory<MyInterface>`, and so the cast fails.

`Factory<T>` is *invariant* (assuming it's a class), which means `Factory<string>` does not derive from `Factory<object>`, even though `string` derives from `object`.

What you're looking for is *covariance*. Unfortunately, classes cannot be variant in C#, but interfaces can, *iiiif* the generic type parameter `T` is only used as an output (e.g., method's return type) and never as an input (e.g., method parameters).

If your factory only uses `T` as an output, then you can define a covariant inteface for it such as:

```
public interface IFactory<out T> {}

public class Factory<T> : IFactory<T> {}
```

Now you can cast `IFactory<T>` where `T:MyInterface` to `IFactory<MyInterface>`